# Angular2 Svg Text attribute binding

Tags: svg, data-binding, angular

I want to create an svg dynamically in Angular 2.

I have several attributes to add like  x, y, text-anchor, font-size, font-family and fill, but only the font-size works for me. The fill doesn't want to work with [ ] around.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100%" width="100%">
     <svg:text
            [attr.x]="0"
            [attr.y]="100"
            [attr.text-anchor]="start"
            [attr.font-size]="29"
            [attr.font-family]="Helvetica"
            attr.fill="#77777">
                <tspan
                    x="0"
                    dy="0">Random Text</tspan>
    </svg:text>
 </svg>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/D0eyyW9flV92rmoh8o85

How can I bind to the attributes listed above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have hardcoded value in `string` format, otherwise angular will look into the component for the variable with that name for updating binding. Also you should specify `fill` property value as `#777` instead of `#777777`. You would be needed `#777777` when you are running application on IE browser.

```
 <svg:text
        [attr.x]="0"
        [attr.y]="100"
        [attr.text-anchor]="start"
        [attr.font-size]="29"
        [attr.font-family]="'Helvetica'"
        [attr.fill]="'#777'">
            <tspan
                x="0"
                dy="0">Random Text</tspan>
</svg:text>
```

Keep in mind each attribute binding inside `[]` sign, you missed the same for `attr.fill`

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/hIpFTYD95PaOr6f6XOR8?p=preview)

Comment: I had to use `[attr.text-anchor]="'start'"` for the text-anchor, but it seems to solve my problem. One thing that doesn't work is the x coordinate. I changed it to 50, but the result was the same. Any idea?

Comment: I can see the change is happening by changing.. look at here http://plnkr.co/edit/FpqOQUUllMrs0ANtCBGu?p=preview

Comment: I have changed the x attribute of text, not the tspan's. Shouldn't both of them work?